# Vue: two different props are changed: one after another, however using nextTick doesn't ensure the ordered change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a `Card` component that has a front and a back side. A `CardList` component displays the cards in an array. The array contains the data associated with each card, which is passed as props to the `Card` components in a `for` cycle.

When the left side of the card is clicked the user is displayed the previous data (the back side of the previous card/the front side of the current side). Moving forward follows the similar logic:

**Card.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <transition  mode="out-in">
       <div v-if="show">
        <p>{{ this.front }}</p>
      </div>

      <div v-else>
        <p>{{ this.back}}</p>
      </div>


    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

...
props:  {
  ...
  front: String,
  back: String,
  show: Boolean
  ...
}

</script>
```

**CardList.vue**:

```
<template>
<div v-if="this.hasCards">

<Card v-for="(card, index) in this.cards" v-bind:key="index" v-show="card.isActive"
  :front="card.front" :back="card.back" :show="page.show"
  v-on:click.stop="this.cardClick($event)"
/>

</div>
</template>

<script>
...
data()  {
  return  {
    cards: [],
    currentCardIndex: -1,
    hasCards: false
  }
}

created()  {
  this.createCards();
}

cardClick(event)  {
  if (this.goBackClick(event))  {
    this.back();
  } else  {
    this.forward();
  }

  this.$nextTick(() =>  {
    // alert shows correct (updated) data
    alert(this.cards[this.currentCardIndex].show);
    // makes the card visible, the old data is briefly displayed
    // despite the correct .show property
    this.cards[this.currentCardIndex].isActive = true;
  });

  ...
}
...
</script>
```

**tl;dr**:

The `back` and `forward` methods update the `show` property, after which the `cardClick` method updated the `isActive` property. However the `show` property is not updated before the `isActive` property is set to `true`, resulting in the user briefly seeing invalid data.

**Detailed question**:

`back` method tries to go either to the previous card's back side, or to the front side of the current card.

`forward` method tries to go either to the next card's front side, or to the current card's back side.

Therefore the `back` and `forward` methods update the `currentCard.show` property (which is passed as a prop to the `Card` component, and is reactive).

The problem I'm encountering is the following:

A user has an ability to move to any card (by specifying its index in a textbox, for instance). Then the card the user has specified is `card.isActive = true`.

However, it may happen so that if the user (after having opened a middle card) wants to go back/forward, they may encounter the following situation:

```
currentCardIndex: 2, currentCard.isActive: true,
 currentCard.show = false (the back side is being displayed)

nextCardIndex: 3, nextCard.isActive: false, 
nextCard.show = false (the last time the user 
viewed this card, it was this card's back side)
```

So when the user clicks on the right side of the current card in order to move forward, the user expects to see the front side of the next card.

The `show` property is updated inside `forward` method, and it works. However sometimes the user briefly sees the back side of the next card, before the front side of the next card is displayed.

I assumed it happens, because while in the code's login the `show = true` (to display the front side of the next card) is updated before (in the `forward` method) the `isActive = true` (in the `cardClick` method), due to asynchronized nature of Vue's prop queue, `isActive = true` happens to go through faster than the `show = true`.

I tried to counter it with using the `nextTick` method, however it didn't help!

The `alert` in the `nextTick` callback behaves as expected - when the user traverses all cards (all cards would have `show = false` at that point) and then chooses a card in the middle, and then clicks to go to the next card, the `alert` displays `true`, meaning the data in the `cards` array has been updated accordingly - to display the front side of the next card. Yet the user still sees a flash of the back side of the next card.

Comment: The problem is probably that you use a transition. Did you try without it?

Comment: @EstusFlask I think that's it! Removed the transition, and it seems to be working! Thank you so much!